# Автосохранение в RAD studio 2010.

Tags: c++builder, delphi

- Есть ли сохранение в RAD stidio 2010?
- Если да, то как оно включается?
- Если нет, то есть ли оно в других средах программирования? Каких?(Интересует C++ Builder и Delphi)

Comment: показан 40130 раз не многовато ли?

Comment: админы обратите внимание!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не из 2010, но может и там есть такое?

Tools -> Options -> Evironment Options ->Autosave Options -> Project desktop

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Проще было бы Ctrl + Shift + S  (Сохранение проекта)